# Issues with Flask Login Manager and React Integration

Tags: reactjs, authentication, flask, session-cookies, web-development-server

I'm working on a web development project (Task Manager) using Flask for the backend and React.js for the frontend. I am trying to implement a single login feature using Flask's Login Manager. In my Flask login route, I succesfully set 'current_user' to the desired value after performing 'login_user(user)'. However, when I move my React component to a new file and send a new request from React to Flask, 'current_user' gets reset to anonymous. @login_required routes are never reached. From my understanding Flask's Login Manager stores a cookie so I am not sure where the cookie is getting lost.

I want to mention that I am relatively new to web development, so please excuse any obvious mistakes in my approach. I have ensured that I have CORS configured in Flask using 'CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)', and each of my requests from React includes credentials ('credentials: 'include'). I am unsure whether this issue is related to cookies or if there is a separate error in my setup or understanding on how this works. I expected current_user to be remembered once logged in so I could use the id from this to retrieve specific user data from the database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.